# octave plot text field size

Tags: plot, octave, font-size

I am adding text to an octave plot using:

h = text(x1, -2, 'x_1');

Then I attempt to change the font size with:

set(h, 'fontsize', 16);

Only the subscript '1' changes in size.  Is that a bug or
am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am running Octave 3.4.0 and gnuplot 4.4.0. I cant reproduce this behaviour. My money is on a bug.